# change attribute value on click, then change back on next click

Tags: jquery

I want to replace #content with #nav at the first click, then after the second click, I want to change #nav back #content. Tho, it only works on the first click, and I can't figure out how to change it back to #content after the second click. I'm not sharp at jQuery yet, but i'm trying to learn. I appreciate all help I can get :)

```
 $('.webbActive').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href', '#content')) {
       $(this).attr('href', '#nav');
    }
    else {
       $(this).attr('href', '#content');
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not comparing the `href` attribute with `#content` in your if, you are changing it.
To get the value from the element you have to call to `attr` with only one parameter: the name of the attribute (check [doc](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)). Try this:

```
 $('.webbActive').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') === '#content') {
       $(this).attr('href', '#nav');
    }
    else {
       $(this).attr('href', '#content');
    }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that worked! Glad to see that I did most of it correct at least.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `if ($(this).attr('href') == '#content')`

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your If condition first, as:

```
$('.webbActive').click(function() {
if ($(this).attr('href') == "#content") {
   $(this).attr('href', '#nav');
}
else {
   $(this).attr('href', '#content');
}
});
```